# Select class but apply style only to one clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have this code

```
<div class="year">
<div class="month" id="month-1"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-2"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-3"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-4"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-5"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-6"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-7"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-8"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-9"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-10"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-11"></div>
<div class="month" id="month-12"></div>
</div>

<script>
document.querySelector(".month").addEventListener("click",function (){
    //here I need to add some code
}
</script>
```

In place where "I need to add some code", I want to write something like this
make color only of clicked element blue

But if I use

```
this.style.color="blue"
```

it will add that style to all div.month.

For example if I clicked on element with ID `month-1`, I only want that particular element to change color.

**ALL ANSWERS ARE CORRECT!! HOW I CAN SELECT ALL OF THEM TO BE CORECT? **

Comment: use event.target property to access the clicked element.

Comment: The `querySelector(".month")` method returns only the first element that matches the selector. This means that you're adding the click listener only to the first `div` which has the class `month`.

Comment: "...  I want only #month-1 to get that style." But that's exactly what you get with the current code?

Comment: Temmu-if I click #month-1 then #month-1 should get style

Comment: check it if you want like this  http://jsfiddle.net/P5DCg/1/

Comment: @Matija But it [is getting the style](https://jsfiddle.net/z8r3056p/). Rather use event delegation, and add the click listener to `.year`, pass the event object to the handler, and check, if a `.month` was clicked, and if so, change the style. [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/z8r3056p/2/). The fiddle snippet also remembers the previous click, and changes its color back to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Titus said the querySelector returns only the first element that matches, we use `getElementsByClassName` if want to get all elements that match the class name. And we loop through the returned collections to bind the listener.

```js
var Months = document.getElementsByClassName("month");

for (var i = 0; i < Months.length; i++) {
    Months[i].addEventListener('click', function() { this.style.color = "#ff0000"; }, false);
}
```

```css
.month { height: 30px; }
```

```html
<div class="year">
<div class="month" id="month-1">1</div>
<div class="month" id="month-2">2</div>
<div class="month" id="month-3">3</div>
<div class="month" id="month-4">4</div>
<div class="month" id="month-5">5</div>
<div class="month" id="month-6">6</div>
<div class="month" id="month-7">7</div>
<div class="month" id="month-8">8</div>
<div class="month" id="month-9">9</div>
<div class="month" id="month-10">10</div>
<div class="month" id="month-11">11</div>
<div class="month" id="month-12">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use hidden checkboxes and labels with "for" attribute defined, so you will not need javascript, css only:

```
.year input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
}
```

demo [here](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/ALLjRG)

If you need exclusive selection - use "radio" instead of "checkbox"

Answer (score 0):

In essence you should use `querySelectorAll` and attach the click event to each one. Try out the code snippet below.

```js
elements = document.querySelectorAll(".month");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="year">
  <div class="month" id="month-1">1</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-2">2</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-3">3</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-4">4</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-5">5</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-6">6</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-7">7</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-8">8</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-9">9</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-10">10</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-11">11</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-12">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `querySelector(".month")` method returns only the first element that matches the selector. This means that you're adding the click listener only to the first `div` which has the class `month`.

In order to get all the elements that have this class (`month`) you can use the `querySelectorAll(...)` function.

Here is an example:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".month")).forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener("click", function (){
                // In this context, you can use "element" or "this" 
                // to access the clicked element.
                element.style.color = "blue";
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="year">
    <div class="month" id="month-1">First</div>
    <div class="month" id="month-2">Second</div>
    <div class="month" id="month-3">Third</div>
    <div class="month" id="month-4">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the document.getElementsByClassName method and then loop through each of the elements in the html collection (months) adding event listeners to each of them, it works pretty well. See below:

```
    var months = document.getElementsByClassName("month")

    for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
         months[i].addEventListener("click",function (){
         this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
         })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event bubbling, by binding event on parent div with class year and applying style with event target to child elements.So don't have to bind event on every child element.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    event.target.style.color = "#ff0000"
}, false);
```

```html
    <div class="year">
  <div class="month" id="month-1">1</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-2">2</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-3">3</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-4">4</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-5">5</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-6">6</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-7">7</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-8">8</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-9">9</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-10">10</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-11">11</div>
  <div class="month" id="month-12">12</div>
</div>
```